# Define $N_h(p) \cap Q$ given certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose for some positive $r,\ $ some finite number of points of $E$ are in $N_r(p) \cap E.$ Let $Q = (N_r(p) \cap E) - \{p\} = \{q_i\}$ and $D = \{d(p, q_i)\}$ with $1 \le i \le n.$ Now let $h = \frac 12 \min D.$

Question: what is $N_h(p) \cap Q?$

Possible answer:  $0 < h < \min D \implies q_i \not \in N_h(p) \implies N_h(p) \cap Q = \emptyset.$

Does this answer make sense to you?

Comment: Are we in real numbers?  A general metric space?  A topological space?  Something else?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.

Comment: @Randall, $E \subset X$ where $X$ is a metric space.

Comment: @zipirovich, thanks. I've been at it ever since yesterday. Can't believe the solution was this easy :)

Comment: Some finite number of points of E are in N_r(p) cap E is vague.  Zero points are finite and if N cap E were infinite then there would still be some finite number of points in N cap E.  Do you mean that N_r(p) cap E is finite?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, $N_r(p) \cap E$ contains a finite number of points of $E.$